# Websites using DHE Diffie-Hellman key exchange

Tags: security, ssl, key, diffie-hellman, starttls

I have created a program that test various security measurements on mailservers. I want to test this but I need to find websites that use DHE.

Can anyone help me find a website for me to test on?
Thanks.

I tried to find various sites that use DHE/DH but cannot seem to find any since they all use ECDHE or RSA.

I use openssl `openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect URL`

To get the data.